# how to turn off l10N for django-money values

Tags: django, templates

I use `{% load l10n %}` and it works great.

But it formats `Money('55652.69924091', 'USD')` (from the package [django-money](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) into `55652.70 USD`, which is generally ok, but in one place i need to get `55652.6992 USD` (decimal places increase to 4).

I tried `{% localize off %}{{ object.value }} {% endlocalize %}` but no effect.

I can do it with `.amount`, but this is ugly.

Answer (score 1):

From [django-money's documentation](https://django-money.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#format-localization) on Format Localization it has a template tag called as `money_localize` which you can use to turn localization on / off for specific values. Hence you can write:

```
{% load djmoney %}
...
{% money_localize object.value off %}
```

Comment: Nope,  the value is still truncated to two decimal places

Comment: Do you set `decimal_places_display` or `decimal_places` on the field by any chance?

Comment: this is a property not a field, and as I wrote if I print value to the log the value is Money('55652.69924091', 'USD') (also object.value.amount prints 55652.69924091